# How do we know "is" is a verb in "Kolkata is a big city"?

Tags: verbs, irregular-forms

I am learning English grammar (parts of speech), and encountered this sentence:

> Kolkata is a big city.

where "is" represents a verb. Could you please help me to understand why?

Comment: "is" is the present form of the verb "be".

Comment: Thank you @keshlam,  does 'be' make the same sense as 'was'?

Comment: It's part of the same irregular verb, whose present infinitive is "to be". I am, you are, it is; I was, you were, it was; I will be, you will be, it will be... and so on.

Comment: @Lambie I suspect it's because a) it doesn't describe an action and b) might not exist in the comparable sentence in OP's first language.

Comment: As a native speaker, "is" as a main verb does seem to indicate an action. It can (clumsily) be replaced by "exists as"; the action is to exist, or more naturally,  to be.

Comment: @nigel222 The definition of a verb is not restricted to words conveying action, so there's no need to wrestle with the attempt to describe existence as an action. Verbs can simply convey a state of being ("is", "tastes", "smells", "lies", "sits", etc), not just an action. Many verbs can be used in either sense. ("I smell a flower", "The flower smells nice")

Comment: Just curious: Would you share what's your native language? Does it not have the equivalent verb?

Comment: Why have you added the tag "irregular forms"? The sentence uses the most basic English grammatical structure with "subject-verb-object" order. This is not irregular.

Comment: @Graham _To be_ is an irregular verb, because it doesn't use the same pattern of endings that most verbs do.  We don't say _I be_, _you be_, _he bes_ and so on.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem But that isn't the question the OP is asking. They are asking how we know the second word in the sentence is a verb. And that is *not* irregular, because it's the most basic structure of English grammar. You could put any other word there, and it would still be recognised as a verb. The sentence might not make sense with some words :) but the first thought of everyone who speaks English would be that it was a verb.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We are often told that verbs are 'action words' and that nouns represent 'things' and stuff like that. It's not true! Verbs, nouns and adjectives and so forth are words that share  certain grammatical properties. The word *is* in *Kolkata is a big city* doesn't represent any kind of action. However, it is a verb because it is a member of the verb category and shares the same *grammatical* properties as other verbs.

In English,  verbs usually have the following properties (amongst others):

**Verb forms**:

Most verbs have the following different verb forms:

- present and past tense forms, e.g. *walk/walked*, *go/went*
- a third person present tense form ending in < s >, e.g. *walks*, *goes*
- an *-ing* form (a gerund-participle), e.g. *walking*, *going*
- a past participle, e.g. *walked*, *gone*
- a base form (used in infinitives, imperatives and subjunctives), e.g. *walk*, *go*

In the Original Poster's example, the word ***is*** is the third person singular  present tense form of the verb *be*. The verb *be* has all of the  forms described above (and more!):

- are/were
- is
- being
- been
- be

**Position:**

- In  a declarative sentence, the verb usually appears after the subject: *She **likes** cheese*

In the OP's sentence the word *is* appears after the subject, *Kolkata*: *Kolkata **is** ...*

**Agreement**:

- In the present tense, the verb form must agree with the grammatical/semantic number of the subject:

> 1. The elephant eats buns. (singular subject, 3rd person single verbform)
> 2. The elephants eat buns. (plural subject, plural verbform)

In the OP's sentence we see a singular subject *Kolkata* and the singular verb from *is.* If we made the subject plural we would need the plural form *are*:

> 3. [Kolkata and New York] **are** big cities.

**Necessary element of sentence**

- Every well-formed sentence in English must have a verb, and every declarative sentence must have a *tensed* verb.

In the Original Poster's example, *Kolkata* is a noun, and *a big city* is a noun phrase, so the verb must be the word *is*!:

> 4. <s>Kolkata</s> **is** <s>a big city</s>.

---

### ***Be* is an auxiliary verb**

More than being a mere verb, we can show that the verb *be* (and therefore the word *is*) is a member of a very special group of verbs, the auxiliary verbs. People used to think an auxiliary was a verb that came before another verb. Nowadays we know that auxiliary verbs are verbs that share special grammatical properties. It doesn't matter whether there's a following verb:

**Auxiliary verbs**

Auxiliary verbs have four special properties:

They contract with *not*, and are necessary to negate sentences:

- She likes cheese.
- *She **likesn't** cheese. (ungrammatical)
- Kolkata is a big city.
- Kolkata **isn't** a big city.

They change places with the subject to make yes/no sentences:

- ***Likes** she cheese? (ungrammatical)
- **Is** Kolkata a big city?

We can use an auxiliary verb without the rest of the verb phrase, so long as the listener can understand the missing words:

- A: Do you like Cheese? B: *I **like** <s>cheese</s>! (ungrammatical)
- A: Is Kolkata a big city? B: It **is** <s>a big city</s>!

We stress auxiliary verbs to emphasise that a sentence is true:

- She **likes** cheese. (weird pronunciation)
- Kolkata **is** a big city. (emphatic).

So not only is the word *is* a verb in the Original Poster's example, it is an elite member of the auxiliary verbs!

Comment: -` the verb "to be" can, and often does, serve as an Auxiliary verb. But in the sentence "*Kolkata is a big city*" it is the main verb, **not** an auxiliary verb.

Comment: @DavidSiegel May I humbly suggest that you consult a modern vetted C21st  grammar source, such as  *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* or *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*? or see [John Lawler's post here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78549/can-be-be-used-with-the-modal-verb-do/78591#78591). Or see [Is 'Helper Verb' Old School](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209132/is-helper-verb-old-school/209189#209189). Or consult Ivan Sag *et al*'s (2020) [*Lessons from the English Auxiliary System*](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/EnglishAuxSystem.pdf)?

Comment: Just because it's the *only* verb doesn't mean it's not an auxiliary verb (according to Wikipedia, one that "adds functional or grammatical meaning to the clause in which it occurs, so as to express tense, aspect, modality, voice, emphasis, etc.") "is" provides a stative aspect to the sentence, if I am applying this definition correctly.

Comment: In this already long answer you didn't address the comparison with "Kolkata is growing".

Comment: @FlorianF I can't quite see how that would address the OP's question. Could you explain?

Comment: In "Kolkata is growing" growing is the verb.  "is" looks to have a binding role, like in "Kolkata is big" (binding to an adjective) or "Kolkata is a big city" (binding to a noun).  What I mean is "is" can be seen as kind of a "glue" word like "of", a role different from a verb.  It might explain why the OP doesn't feel "is" is a verb.

Answer (score 23):

In English the **copula**, "be", is a verb.

In other languages, the copula is not a verb. For example, Korean.

The word "be" has forms: be, am, is, are, was, were, being, been.

"Is" is the third-person present form of "be".

Answer (score 1):

"is" is part of the verb to be: (singular) I am; you are; he/she/it is; (plural) we are; you are; they are.

In this context "be" indicates an existence of some sort.

The meaning of *Kolkata **is** a big city" approximates to *Kolkata **exists as** a big city*.

The use of "is" (and the rest of the verb "to be") is to supply a verb to a sentence like this because, in general terms, all sentences must have a verb.